# gke-metrics-agent multiple error related to prometheus

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed a new app to GKE, I see the GKE dashboard has thousands of errors on gke-metrics-agent:

[image]

It uses a high resource.

I checked the logs, and I saw all errors related to Prometheus, but I didn't find a way to troubleshoot these errors:
[image]

cluster version:
1.18.12-gke.1206

What are these errors, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Could you share how did you deployed Prometheus? Could you check if all your pods are running as expected? Could you `$ kubectl describe <pod-name> -n <namespace>` gke-metrics-agent pod and prometheus pod? Also could you `$ kubectl logs <pod name> -n <namespace>` of gke and prometheus pod to check what errors you find there? Some additional debugging steps can be found in [this K8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/)

Comment: @PjoterS This is the case on a fresh GKE cluster without installing anything extra such as Prometheus AFAIK.

Comment: How did you deployed this prometheus? Did you use helm, deployment or Google Click to deploy? Id like to replicate this on my test cluster.

Comment: I didn't deploy Prometheus yet, Just our custom deployments are applied, as @dustinmoris said, it's a new cluster without Prometheus installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like some GKE `1.18.12-gke-X` versions have bug where `gke-metrics-agent` produces a lot of `Warning` messages.

There is already a `Public Issue Tracker` ticket for this bug. You can follow updates regarding this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179260610). You can also use `(+1)` to indicate that you are affected by this bug.

Workaround of this issue is to use newer version - `1.18.14-gke.1200+`

Comment: Thanks, but upgrading to 1.18.14-gke.1200+ is not possible.

The regular release channel is on 1.18.12-* and the rapid channel is on 1.19.*, there is nothing in between as far as I can see.

Comment: Upgrading to the rapid channel now :)

Comment: @dustinmoris you can also use `Static version`. In static-version drop-down menu you can choose versions `1.18.14-gke.1200`, `1.18.14-gke.1600`, `1.18.15-gke.1100` and `1.18.15-gke.1500`.

Comment: Upgrading to 1.19 hasn't resolved this for me though.

Comment: If you are still getting this error, please use `Static version`.

Comment: Doesn't work as it says that there is no static version available in the Rapid channel and you cannot downgrade either. So basically it means that I'm stuck with this issue now until it actually gets fixed -.-

Comment: It's resolved for me when I upgraded to 1.19.7-gke.1500, Thank you @PjoterS

Comment: What options am I left with? Do I need to restart some pods or nodes for the new version to stop producing these errors?

Comment: @dustinmoris I have just tested 2 versions from `Rapid Channel` - `1.19.7-gke.2503` and `1.20.2-gke.2500`. It looks like those errors are generated for ~10 minutes. After that time there are no `prometheus` errors. In older versions like `1.18.12-gke.1210` those errors are generating all the time.

Comment: @PjoterS Thank you for looking into this. It's odd, but all your suggestions seem to have no effect for me, even when I create a brand new cluster. I've waited more than 10 minutes and I am still getting the same amount of the same errors. I've attached more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475701/new-gke-cluster-logging-thousands-of-errors?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Didn't work for me. I tried it with versions `1.18.15-gke.1500` and `1.18.16-gke.300`.

Comment: Did you enabled `NodeLocalDNS` in your GKE cluster?

Comment: @PjoterS Yes. The warnings went away after disabling it.

Comment: This issue was already forwarded to Google Team via Issue Tracker. @dustinmoris already created another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66475701/new-gke-cluster-logging-thousands-of-errors?noredirect=1&lq=1) where it has been found that this addon reoccurs issue.