# New GKE cluster logging thousands of errors

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

After creating a fresh new Kubernetes cluster in Google Kubernetes Engine I am seeing a lot of errors in Google Cloud logging related to the metrics agent.

I have had that problem with an existing cluster on version `1.18.x`. Then I upgraded to `1.19.x` after the [suggestion that this would fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66314901/gke-metrics-agent-multiple-error-related-to-prometheus/66371927?noredirect=1#comment117363486_66371927). However, the problem persisted so I upgraded to `1.20.x` and still no change.

Eventually I created a new cluster with the most recent Kubernetes version and still see hundreds of errors being logged immediately after:

```
gcloud beta container clusters create "my-cluster-1" \
    --project "my-project-1" \
    --zone "europe-west2-a" \
    --no-enable-basic-auth \
    --release-channel "rapid" \
    --cluster-version "1.20.2-gke.2500" \
    --machine-type "e2-standard-2" \
    --image-type "COS_CONTAINERD" \
    --disk-type "pd-standard" \
    --disk-size "100" \
    --metadata disable-legacy-endpoints=true \
    --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append" \
    --num-nodes "1" \
    --enable-stackdriver-kubernetes \
    --enable-private-nodes \
    --master-ipv4-cidr "172.16.0.0/28" \
    --enable-ip-alias \
    --network "projects/my-project-1/global/networks/default" \
    --subnetwork "projects/my-project-1/regions/europe-west2/subnetworks/default" \
    --default-max-pods-per-node "110" \
    --no-enable-master-authorized-networks \
    --addons HorizontalPodAutoscaling,HttpLoadBalancing,NodeLocalDNS,GcePersistentDiskCsiDriver \
    --enable-autoupgrade \
    --enable-autorepair \
    --max-surge-upgrade 1 \
    --max-unavailable-upgrade 0 \
    --workload-pool "my-project-1.svc.id.goog" \
    --enable-shielded-nodes \
    --node-locations "europe-west2-a","europe-west2-b","europe-west2-c"
```

In Google Cloud logging I check for errors using this query:

```
severity=ERROR
AND (resource.labels.container_name:"gke-metrics-agent"
OR resource.labels.container_name="metrics-server-nanny")
resource.labels.cluster_name="my-cluster-1"
```

[image]

As per another suggestion I waited for more than 10 minutes and was still getting the same amount of errors being logged:

[image]

---

UPDATE 05 March 2021

Creating a new test cluster via the UI. Not changing anything except the cluster name set to `test-cluster-1` and the Zone to `europe-west-2a` and the Kubernetes version to the latest of the rapid channel as per suggestion:

[image]

Immediately after creating the new cluster I'm getting hundreds of errors logged:

[image]

I'll observe for 15-20 minutes to see if it remains that way.

Comment: I've run a couple of test scenarios. It seems that one of your configuration flags causes a reappearance of `prometheus` error entry. I've tested your config without `--node-locations`,  `--workload-pool` and `--network`.  Could you create `GKE` cluster v `1.20.2-gke.2500` using UI without any changes? You would still get a hundrets/thousands of this error messages?

Comment: @PjoterS Thanks. I have just created a new cluster and updated my answer to include screenshots of my progress. Waiting now for about 15-20 minutes to see if I'll keep getting errors.

Comment: Looks like that works! No more errors. Ok, so now the question is which setting is causing the reappearance of prometheus errs.

Comment: New cluster with 3 zones specified for the nodes also works.

Comment: Ok I think I figured out what it is. When enabling `NodeLocalDNS` then errors appear.

Comment: Happy to hear it is resolved! Do u want me to post it as the answer or you will do by yourself? This could probably help to the community as well.

Comment: I don't mind. Happy for you to post it as an answer. Thanks for the help! Do you work for Google? If yes can this please get logged as a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66314901/gke-metrics-agent-multiple-error-related-to-prometheus), `GKE cluster` v `1.18.12-gke.1206` contained bug which logged hundreds of `Prometheus` errors:

```
github.com/prometheus/prometheus/scrape.(*scrapeLoop).scrapeAndReport
```

This issue has been already reported via `Issue Tracker`. This issue has been fixed in versions `1.18.14-gke.1200+` and `1.19.6-gke.600+`.
New cluster with mentioned versions or newer contains a fix for this issue.

OP's cluster configuration contained a flag which caused this issue to reoccur. I have tested a few scenarios but OP @dustinmoris found that it was caused by the `NodeLocalDNS` addon.

Enabling one addon: `NodeLocalDNS` reoccurs the issue. It was tested on versions: `1.20.2-gke.2500`, `1.19.7-gke.1500`, `1.19.7-gke.2503`, `1.18.15-gke.1102`.

Proper comments were already added to `Issue Tracker`. For all updates, please check [this Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179260610).

Comment: Many thanks for the help and for logging it in the official issue tracker!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help if you're using the Autopilot mode, since you can't change the settings